# Rspec syntax error, expecting to close a statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm playing around with rspec and running into an issue trying to check with Dir.glob.  It looks like I'm having an error with closing out my Dir.stub statement, but all of my parentheses match?

```
syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)  
Facter::Util::Resolution.stubs(:exe...
```

The code is

```
Dir.stubs(:glob).with("/opt/test/cli-*/checker").and_return(double("glob", :'exists?' => true)
Facter::Util::Resolution.stubs(:exec).with('checker -version').returns("Version:  1.5")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

closing paren missing `)` .

```
.and_return(double("glob", :'exists?' => true) <~~ here
```

Write as

```
.and_return(double("glob", :'exists?' => true))
```

Comment: Embarrassed I even made a post for that, thanks for the extra pair of eyes!